# How to capture multiple error columns in SSIS data flow

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, ssis, etl

I have a situation where I want to capture all the columns that are causing errors. To do this I have a data flow which was working fine, I changed the destination data type of a column that caused the data flow to fail, using a script component, I was able to capture the column name that caused the issue, now I introduced one more data type change but now it is capturing the column name of the latest change but not the two column names that have issues.

Is there a way to insert two or more column names that are causing data flow to fail into a column seperated by commas in a destination flat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment I would like to suggest a script component and perform data validation there:

Add a new output called errors with three columns:

KeyToRecord [the correct dataType]
strDataInCol string
ErrorReason string

Then run through a variety of checks:

```
if(Row.Col1.Length > 50)
{
    OutputError.AddRow();
    OutputError.KeyToRecord = Row.RecordKey;
    OutputError.strDataInCol = Row.Col1.ToString();
    OutputError.ErrorReason = "Column1 is greater than 50 chars";
}
```

and so on through all of your checks.

This will give you a list of errors within your file.

Comment: I have used this and it did help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it is not clear how you are capturing the error column. I will assume that you are using the Error output to do that.

I don't think you can capture more than one error in a row. On each row, if an error occurred while inserting a column the insertion is canceled and the other columns insertion is not done. So if one of the other column values will cause an issue it will not be identified.

If you are looking to validate all values within a row, you should implement your own logic using a script component.

Comment: Yes, I was looking to see if there is a way to capture all columns, from your answer it seems that its not a possibility. Thank you.

Comment: @RaviMadhav you have to implement your own validation process within a script component (or other components)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional split to redirect the rows that fail a test.

For example, you are ultimately loading to a varchar(50) then you can test that column with len(column)>50.

You can have as many tests as you want (additional columns) but like a case statement, you only catch the first trigger event.

By redirecting all the bad rows, it will let you load all good rows and deal with the bad rows individually.

Let's say you have two tests. You can pinpoint whether or not both tests failed with multiple conditional splits but most programs usually just have one conditional split for a good or no good in the entirety of all tests.

Comment: Thanks Keith, may be I did not state my question correct, all I want to know is if there is a way to get all the column names that caused a data flow fail. From the previous answer by Hadi, it seems that its not possible.